# Video won't play correctly

Tags: video, youtube

I'm new to linux and I've installed ubuntu 12.04 on a dual boot PC. Whenever I play something on Youtube or Iplayer the image is compressed to the left half of the screen and the colours are wrong. The sound works fine. The PC has on board graphics Intel® 865G x86/MMX/SSE2 and I have updated the drivers and installed Ubuntu restricted extras. I've got Flash v 11.2 and the plug-in's seem to be installed correctly. The problem occurs on both Firefox and Chrome. I think the problem may be related to Flash but I'm not sure. Can anyone advise me on how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Do you remember how you got the flash plug-in? Are you using Chromium or Google Chrome?

Comment: Hello Dash, the Firefox plug-in was loaded automatically. I'm using Chromium and it's flash plug-in was also installed automatically.

Comment: normally video on hdd playing fine??

Comment: No video plays properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps re-installing Flash will fix this issue.

First, open a Terminal. Then run the commands below:

`sudo apt-get purge flashplugin-installer`

This command will remove Flash and the configuration files associated with it.

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer`

This command will update the repositories sources and install the Flash plug-in.

Comment: Have followed your instructions but it has made no difference. I tried to post a screen shot but I too new on this site to be allowed to do it.

Comment: You can upload the picture to [Imgur](http://imgur.com) and add a link to it in your post. Also, can you download Google Chrome and see if it has issues also? It comes with a newer/different Flash version.

Comment: Thanks Dash. Google Chrome works perfectly. I appreciate your help.